# Change button "return" to the button "next" in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

My application is for IOS devices, like the iPhone.
I have several *textfields* in my application, when I click on a text box to enter text, the keyboard appears including a "Return" button. I want to change the "Return" button to a "Next" button using Objective-C, so that when I tap on the "NEXT" button the cursor should go to the next *textfield* in the application.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your viewdidLoad add:

```
[textField setReturnKeyType: UIReturnKeyNext];
```

and for your info :

```
typedef enum {
    UIReturnKeyDefault,
    UIReturnKeyGo,
    UIReturnKeyGoogle,
    UIReturnKeyJoin,
    UIReturnKeyNext,
    UIReturnKeyRoute,
    UIReturnKeySearch,
    UIReturnKeySend,
    UIReturnKeyYahoo,
    UIReturnKeyDone,
    UIReturnKeyEmergencyCall,
} UIReturnKeyType;
```

and it is well documented in apples site :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html

Answer (score 0):

You can check at Storyboard itself :

[image]

If programmatically, then `[textField setReturnKeyType: UIReturnKeyNext];`

Then, `return key` doesn't do anything in a text field by default, you need override this delegate method `textFieldShouldReturn` :

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == txtField1) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    } else if (textField == txtField2) {
        [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    }// else if (){ 

    return YES;
}
```